# same java codes, different performance?

Tags: java, apache, network-programming

I'm testing my customized web server with some tiny java programs, but i'm getting some odd results.
My starting code is made of two parts that HTTP-GET the same URL from my web server that are placed consecutively one after another and the result is the time performance of each part.
as you can see everything are the same in each part but the second part is always a bit slower.

I'm testing each of these two part in a loop with a 100 iteration and getting the average time  but the second part is still slower. i'm wondering why this is happening? same code except the sequence of execution and different performance.
here is my simple code:

```
    long times1 = 0;
    long times2 = 0;

            for(int i = 0;i < 100; i++){
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        URL url;
        url = new URL("http://127.o.o.1/i");
        HttpURLConnection http_Con;
        http_Con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        http_Con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        http_Con.getResponseCode();
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        times1 += endTime - startTime;
    }
    System.out.println(times1/100);

    for(int i = 0;i < 100; i++){
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        URL url1;
        url1 = new URL("http://127.o.o.1/i");
        HttpURLConnection http_Con1;
        http_Con1 = (HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
        http_Con1.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        http_Con1.getResponseCode();
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        times2 += endTime - startTime;
    }
    System.out.println(times2/100);


    if (times1/100 < times2/100)
        System.out.println("times2 is bigger");
    else
        System.out.println("times1 is bigger");
    System.out.println(times2/100-times1/100);
}
```

output1:

```
32114390812772
32124690872679
times2 is bigger
10300059907
```

output2:

```
32291342784487
32302050988456
times2 is bigger
10708203969
.
.
.
```

P.S:
my web server is Apache base and i did nothing to the networking or any performance related part of it.

Comment: sometimes the server fall into round hibernation and wake them up takes time, it's from a standstill and it is necessary to make more inquiries.

Comment: you can try a `HttpURLConnection.disconnect()` and check if is only a problem of resource allocation the cause of your different performance

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely wrong: `times1 += endTime + startTime;`

What you're doing here is adding both the `endTime` and the `startTime`, while you actually only need the difference. This is causing huge numbers that are around the year 3000.

Comment: i correct that thank you but that's not a matter to final result

Comment: What's the new output you're getting with this change?

Comment: times2 is still bigger for every test

Comment: 1875618
69335472
times2 is bigger
67459854

Comment: I suggest you stop using the nanotimes and start using a `StopWatch`. This class is meant for exactly this. If your findings are still out of the ordinary, edit your post with them.